# How to silence warning in Swift 3

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I am using restKit + core data stack. It's not like it's a big problem, but it just bugs me. This is the only warning in my code.
Maybe I am doing something wrong with this. Just give me some way to silence this.

> Warning: Immutable value 'persistentStore' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it!

```
{
    let persistentStore: NSPersistentStore?
    do {
        try persistentStore = managedObjectStore?.addSQLitePersistentStore(atPath: storePath, fromSeedDatabaseAtPath: nil, withConfiguration: nil, options: nil)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error migrating store")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use `persistentStore`, then simply:

`try _ = managedObjectStore?.addSQLitePersistentStore(atPath: storePath, fromSeedDatabaseAtPath: nil, withConfiguration: nil, options: nil)`

Comment: Tx, i figured it out in later, its swift 3 thingy. This happened after code transition.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **persistentStore** with **_**. This warning is newly added in swift 3 if returned value is not used.